# Why is /dev/sdxy not recommended when using fstab?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount, fstab

I was reading [`fstab`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab) documentation and they mentioned it is not recommended to use `/dev/sdxy` in `fstab`

```
Device : /dev/sdxy (not recommended)
```

I use the same method to mount my hard disk every time. I would like to know why it is not recommended and should I change it. If yes what option should I provide?

```
/dev/sdb1       /run/media/storage          ntfs-3g     defaults    1 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it's not recommended is because it doesn't point to a fixed device.

For example if you have 2 hard drives plugged into a pc the first will be called 
/dev/sda
the second will be called
/dev/sdb
Now if you where to plug in a third drive or even a usb stick for that matter. There is no guarantee that the new drive would become /dev/sdc it may just happen that that drive becomes /dev/sdb making you mount the wrong drive. Same with unplugging or even potentially changing some bootorder settings in the bios. Or just at random.

Granted it will work fine most of the time and if you have an usb drive plugged in during boot it will generally get a higher number then the drives already in the system. Using UUID's instead will not break in the same way.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ ls -l /dev/disk/by-id/
...

$ lsblk
...
```

With `/dev/sdXY` the part after`/dev/` depends on where you connect your disk, physically - depending on the situation the `sdXY`-part might change (e.g. as you add one more disk).

Using the names listed under `/dev/disk/by-id/` you will get the disk looked up regardless of where it is connected (to some degree at least).